# Error:(5,19) java: package org.mockito does not exist

Tags: java, testing, intellij-idea, junit, mockito

I wanted to learn a bit about Mockito, but when I run my test class I get the following errors, even though I import the package:

[image]

What do I have to do, to make the code work?

[image]

Comment: Importing a package won't do anything unless that package is also in your classpath. do you use a tool like maven or gradle to handle your dependencies?

Comment: Is Mockito imported in your build.gradle file?

Comment: In general there are _main_ and _test_ sources. Only test sources need to have Mockito classes, a library dependency to the Mockito jar (test scope). So check your gradle config, and check that the using class resides under test.

Comment: Please read [no pictures of exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) / [no pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Then use the [edit] link to replace screen shots of text with nicely formatted/indented text within your quesiton.

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. What matters how exactly your project is setup. And finally: putting up question here, to then walk away and not be able to respond to such comments that ask you for more information ... not very polite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this in your build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
...
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core'
}
```

**note:** the build.gradle file **must** be located in the application root, ie: `FantasticFeastsTemplate/`.

Hope that helps!